# density of a set, multiples of irrational number mod irrational number

Tags: number-theory

The set $\{n\sqrt{2}\bmod 1\colon n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $(0,1)$, it follows from the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ (a well-known fact, that fractional parts of multiples of irrational number form a dense in $(0,1)$).

Is $\{n\sqrt{2}\bmod \sqrt{3}\colon n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ dense in $(0,\sqrt{3})$ ?

Is $\{n\sqrt{2}\bmod \pi\colon n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ dense in $(0,\pi)$ ?

Probably the answer is yes.
Can it be derived from the above, or this is a completely different result requiring much more advanced theory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for $\{na \,\text{mod} \,b : n \in \mathbb N\}$ to be dense in $(0,b)$, it is necessary and sufficient that $a/b$ be irrational. This is true for $b=1$, as your question seems to acknowledge. The general case can be derived from the special case $b=1$ by using the transformation $f : (0,1) \to (0,b)$ defined by $f(t)=bt$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The group generated by $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt3$ has not a minimal positive element since $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt3$ are algebraically independent, so it is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\{n\sqrt 2 mod\sqrt 3\}$ is dense in $(0,3)$